# Google Maps v3 automatically refreshing on DOM activity?

Tags: google-maps, dom

- I'm currently working with the [Google Maps API v3 Geocoder Tool](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html).
- I've inserted my own code in a separate script which queries a data source and then updates a  with the results.
- When I debug and step through my code, my div is updated and then it goes to main.js (located on maps.gstatic.com) at this line:

```
21R.addDomListenerOnce = function(a, b, c, d) {
    var e = R[F](a, b, function() {
        evb;
        return crc
    }, d);
    return e
};
R.Q = function(a, b, c, d) {
    c = Ne(c, d);
    return RF
};

function Ne(a, b) {
    return function(c) {
        return bhc
    }
}
R.bind = function(a, b, c, d) {
    return RE
};
R.addListenerOnce = function(a, b, c) {
    var d = R[E](a, b, function() {
        dvb;
        return crc
    });
    return d
};
R.forward = function(a, b, c) {
    return RE
};
R.oa = function(a, b, c, d) {
    return RF
};
```

- If I keep stepping through, it hard refreshes the page, and my div update is lost.

How do I avoid this refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error and hacking, it looks like my problem was in the style sheet `display: none;` not being changed later in the code.

I also moved my buttons out of the form in the fear it might have been involved in an HTTP Post.